# TDBText not updating in Delphi, other data aware controls work

Tags: delphi, vcl, data-aware

I've taken over a project in Delphi XE4 and I've added some data aware controls to the project.  The TDBGrid seems to work fine, but none of the TDBText controls are displaying anything - and it has me stumped.  I can throw a TDBEdit on the form and hook it up and it works just fine.

Can anyone think of something that would prevent a TDBText control from working?

Comment: Maybe the wrong datatype in the field list or the query?

Comment: Did you forget to set up the DataSource and DataField connections (or use the wrong datasource)? I've never seen a case where a TDBText wouldn't update except when either the field it was connected to was empty, or it was connected to the wrong datasource (for instance, a second copy used for child forms or lookups).

Comment: @KenWhite No all the wiring is correct, and things work fine outside this project.  I've been busy stripping it back and rewrititing chunks of it but still no success.  I had thought it might have redefined a type or something, but not that I can see.  TDBEdits work fine so I have used these as a stop gap measure.